# Numerically integrating two functions iteratively

Tags: python, numpy

I have two functions, dV/dt and dn/dt which I would like to numerically integrate throughout time to find V and n. Throughout time, there will also be a stepwise increase in a constant b which is included in the dV/dt function.

I do have the initial values for v and n at t=0 (and nx and ny).

a is a constant

```
dV/dt=-n**3*(v-a)+b

dn/dt=-(n-nx)/ny

f(v)=[nx,ny]
```

The tricky part comes with the definition of nx and ny; they are values retrieved from a function f(v). Thus, they change with v.

So I believe I need a function that will provide me with iterations of v and n over time as the constant b changes, and I need to retrieve both via numerical integration.
I have tried using trapz and odeint, but I have been struggling to actually use them due to my inexperience with Python.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough equations? That's a lot of unknowns. Do `nx` and `ny` have anything to do with `n` or are they just coincidentally named?

Comment: I may have missed some - unfortunately there are many other constants which bloat the equations so I only included these for space. nx and ny are related to n, nx is the steady state value for n (what it goes to over time, hence why n-nx=dn/dt=0). I forgot to mention that I have the initial values of v, n, nx, and ny - it's in the main post now.

Comment: I assume `v` is the same as `V`? Have you thought about using [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for this?